# How I create dynamic routes separate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, link-to

> **I got link on show like below**

[image]

I Want **http://localhost:3000/admin/flipcart** 
[image]

(flipcart is company name so i want each company separate link.)

If I do http://localhost:3000/admin/flipcart so it show flipcart's show page with out login and authentication.

So how can i do.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: You can use slug instead of id. Have a look at https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730 and https://hackernoon.com/using-custom-slugs-for-rails-urls-500eb3f58f3c. Both the articles explains what you want.

Comment: actually i got show page and i want to create a company separate page to company owner

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this inside your routes.rb:

```
get '/admin/:company', as: :admin_company_index, to: 'admin#index'
```

Then inside the controller just load the company passed through params before you perform any actions:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_company

  private

  def load_company
    @company = Company.where(["name = :c", {c: params[:company]} ])
  end
end
```

Comment: 2.2.3 :014 > @company = Company.where(["name = :c", {c: "flipcart"} ])
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE (name = 'flipcart')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>   I got Nill Response Can you explain this??

Comment: @RonakBhatt It may not be finding it since it's a case sensitive query, I'm also assuming there is a column called 'name', maybe try something like: Company.first(conditions: [ "lower(name) = ?", params[:company].to_s.downcase ])